# Plotting points using multiple colors with `ListPlot`

Tags: plotting

I've got two sets of points, plotted with `ListPLot`.  I would like the second set to have one point of each color specified.  I've tried using `Directive` but cannot seem to find the correct syntax.

```
A[q_] := Cos[q/20]; 

Show[ListPlot[Table[{q, A[q]}, {q, Range[100, 150]}]], 
     ListPlot[Table[{q, A[q]}, {q, Range[110, 125, 5]}], 
                PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[Large], Red},  
                              {PointSize[Large], Orange},      
                              {PointSize[Large], Blue},   
                              {PointSize[Large], Purple}}], 
                Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: `ListPlot[List /@ Table[{q, A[q]}, {q, Range[110, 125, 5]}], 
 PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[Large], Red}, {PointSize[Large], 
    Orange}, {PointSize[Large], Blue}, {PointSize[Large], Purple}}]`

Comment: Thank you very much!  I would like to understand this.  `List /@` maps `List` to each ordered pair, essentially making each pair of coordinates a list of a list?  Why does this work?

Comment: `ListPlot` accepts multiple sets of data as an argument, in the format of `{list1, list2, list3, ...}`. So I just made each point into a list of points (actually a list consisting of a single point) instead. That makes your syntax for `PlotStyle` work

Comment: That's great!  Thank you for the explanation!  That also answers what would be my next question:  "Why do we need to repeat `PointSize[Large]`?"  Probably we can use `Map` again, or a similar construct.

Comment: `p[a_] := {PointSize[Large], a};   p /@ {Red, Orange, Blue, Purple}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments!  Here is the result:

```
A[q_] := Cos[q/20]; 

p[a_] := {PointSize[Large], a}; 

Show[ListPlot[Table[{q, A[q]}, {q, Range[100, 150]}]],  
      ListPlot[List /@ Table[{q, A[q]}, {q, Range[110, 125, 5]}], 
            PlotStyle -> p /@ {Red, Orange, Blue, Purple}], 
            Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]